# Centralizar itens de uma DIV

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Como eu faço pra manter esses três itens centralizados? Reparem que sobra um espaço no lado direito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CSS

```
div.menu {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 30%;
    max-width: 30%;
    font-size: 110%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu a:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">Item 1</a>
  <a href="#">Item 2</a>
  <a href="#">Item 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ou estou ficando meio desatento ou não consegui identificar esse espaço do lado direito?

Comment: tenta fazer uma divisão 100/quantidade de links.

Comment: Centralizar LI ou DIV será a mesma coisa, pois as propriedades display:block|inline-block|table e float:left|right afetam o comportamento de quase todos elementos, basta alterar os seletores do CSS na resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169088/3635 que já resolve ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal apenas alterar o display para  `display: table` da `div` e o da tag `a` para `display:table-cell;`. Para completar, coloque o `width: 100%` na `div`. Dessa forma além de não ter espaço causado pelo `padding`, você deixa algo para adicionar mais itens e ele "ajustar" o `width` para você.

Veja dois exemplos abaixo, um com 3 items no menu e outro com 5 items. Ambos utilizando o mesmo CSS.

```css
div.menu {
  display: table;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 110%;
  background-color: #333;
}
div.menu a {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
div.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">Item 1</a>
  <a href="#">Item 2</a>
  <a href="#">Item 3</a>
</div>


<br/>
<br/>

<div class="menu">
  <a href="#">Item 1</a>
  <a href="#">Item 2</a>
  <a href="#">Item 3</a>
  <a href="#">Item 4</a>
  <a href="#">Item 5</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `calc` do CSS para calcular o tamanho do coluna.

```
width: calc(100% / 3); /* Altera aqui */

min-width: 30%; /* Tira isso */ 
max-width: 30%; /* Tira isso */
```