# Como distribuir imagens horizontalmente por igual dentro de um elemento section?

Tags: css

Tenho a situação abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que as 04 imagens sejam distribuídas horizontalmente por igual dentro do espaço delimitado pela `section`, independente da largura do navegador. Para não ficar com espaço vago como pode-se observar a direita.

Busquei diversas alternativas, mas nada chegou ao resultado desejado.

```css
section.destaquestutisticos{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 2px #FF8922 solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section.destaquestutisticos h1{
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #FF8922;
}

figure.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas{
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  font-size: 16px;

}
figure.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas a{
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color:#222222;
}
figure.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<section class="destaquestutisticos">

    <h1>Destaques de Guarapari</h1>

        <figure class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
                <a href="comidas_tipicas.asp" title="Comidas típicas | Guarapari">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="200" height="150" title="Comidas típicas | Guarapari">
                <figcaption>Comidas típicas</figcaption>
                </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
                <a href="parques.asp" title="Parques | Guarapari">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="200" height="150" title="Parques | Guarapari">
                <figcaption>Parques</figcaption>
                </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
                <a href="praias.asp" title="Praias de Guarapari">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="200" height="150" title="Praias de Guarapari">
                <figcaption>Praias</figcaption>
                </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
                <a href="turismo-rural-guarapari.asp" title="Turismo rural | Guarapari">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="200" height="150" title="Turismo rural | Guarapari">
                <figcaption>Turismo rural</figcaption>
                </a>
        </figure>

    </section>
```

Comment: Use "%" ao invés de "px" para maior responsividade nos navegadores. Deste jeito o espaçamento será igual independente do navegador ou resolução.

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff Não funcinou, aí ele quebra linha.

Comment: eu usaria flexbox. é a melhor forma de organizar itens atualmente. estude a respeito.

Comment: Esta resposta é equivalente https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/169088/3635, só trocar os <li> por figure.

Comment: Gladison, alguma resposta te atende ? Ou ainda é uma pergunta sem resposta?

Answer (score 3):

Vamos la,

```css
section.destaquestutisticos{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 2px #FF8922 solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

section.destaquestutisticos h1{
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #FF8922;
}

.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  

}

img{width: 100%;}

.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas a{
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color:#222222;
}
.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<section class="destaquestutisticos">

    <h1>Destaques de Guarapari</h1>

        <div class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
                <a href="comidas_tipicas.asp" title="Comidas típicas | Guarapari">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="" height="150" title="Comidas típicas | Guarapari">
                <figcaption>Comidas típicas</figcaption>
                </a>
        </div>
  
 <div class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
                <a href="parques.asp" title="Parques | Guarapari">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="" height="150" title="Parques | Guarapari">
                <figcaption>Parques</figcaption>
                </a>
        </div>

        <div class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
                <a href="praias.asp" title="Praias de Guarapari">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="" height="150" title="Praias de Guarapari">
                <figcaption>Praias</figcaption>
                </a>
        </div>

        <div class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
                <a href="turismo-rural-guarapari.asp" title="Turismo rural | Guarapari">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="" height="150" title="Turismo rural | Guarapari">
                <figcaption>Turismo rural</figcaption>
                </a>
        </div>


       
    </section>
```

Acredito que seja isso.

**O que foi feito**

- Retirado a definição `width` diretamente do `HTML`.
- Troca de `figure` para `div`.
- Toda `div` pro padrão provoca uma quebra de linha, então é necessario o `display: inline-block` para que essa quebra não seja realizada.
- Como a `section` tem uma largura de `100%` e são 4 imagens a serem exibidas horizontalmente, basta dividir 100 pelo número de imagens. Resultado = 25. Isso que dizer que cada imagem irá ocupar um espaço de `25%` da `section`, no entanto existem outros estilos aplicados como padding por exemplo que faz com que o tamanho original seja maior que `25%`, nessa situação passei o valor para `24%` para que não haja quebra involuntária de linha.
- O conteúdo da `section` passa a ser centralizado para arrumar de forma centralizada as imagens.
- `H1` agora tem `text-align: left`, para que não fique centralizado juntamente com as imagens.

**Se desprendendo do número fixo de imagens**

Colocamos uma situação hipotética que agora sua `section` precisará apresentar mais ou menos do que apenas 4 imagens.

Obviamente tudo ficaria desconfigurado, porque o código está definido apenas para 4 imagens.

Para fugirmos dessa situação podemos adicionar um pouco de **javascript (jquery)**.

Dessa forma, se tivermos 1,2,3,4.. imagens, elas irão ocupar o espaço horizontal da `section` sem a quebra de linha.

Segue um exemplo com apenas 2 imagens.

```js
var qnt = $('.destaquestutisticos .destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas').length;

var result = 100/qnt;
result = result -1;

$('.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas').css('width', result+'%');
```

```css
section.destaquestutisticos{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 2px #FF8922 solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

section.destaquestutisticos h1{
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #FF8922;
}

.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas{
  display: inline-block;
 
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  

}

img{width: 100%;}

.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas a{
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color:#222222;
}
.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="destaquestutisticos">

    <h1>Destaques de Guarapari</h1>

        <div class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
                <a href="comidas_tipicas.asp" title="Comidas típicas | Guarapari">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="" height="150" title="Comidas típicas | Guarapari">
                <figcaption>Comidas típicas</figcaption>
                </a>
        </div>
  
 <div class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
                <a href="parques.asp" title="Parques | Guarapari">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="" height="150" title="Parques | Guarapari">
                <figcaption>Parques</figcaption>
                </a>
        </div>

     
       
    </section>
```

Comment: Por favor, [edit] sua resposta e explique o que você fez. Colocar apenas o código não ajuda em muito, pois ele pode até ser simples para você, mas para muitos outros usuários não será. Vale comentar que desta forma as imagens ficam deformadas. Esse é o resultado esperado?

Comment: float+inline-block? Não é melhor só inline-block ou só float?

Comment: Acredito que neste caso o float foi só um deslize em não ser apagado Guilherme, se apagarmos a situação é praticamente a mesma. O uso apenas de um ou de outro é realmente melhor.

Answer (score 1):

**O CSS**

Pensando no responsivo, vamos deixar nossos itens em % para 4 colunas seguindo dessa forma:

Para cada item apliquei 25% em width

Selecionamos o primeiro item para zerar o margin usando o seletor “:first-of-type”.

```css
section.destaquestutisticos{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 2px #FF8922 solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section.destaquestutisticos h1{
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  color: #FF8922;
}

figure.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas{
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
display: inline-block;
width: 25%;
position: relative;

}

figure.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas:first-of-type {
   margin-left: 0;
}

figure.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 0 5px;
}

figure.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas a{
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color:#222222;
}
figure.destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas{
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<section class="destaquestutisticos">

<h1>Destaques de Guarapari</h1>

    <figure class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
            <a href="comidas_tipicas.asp" title="Comidas típicas | Guarapari">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="200" height="150" title="Comidas típicas | Guarapari">
            <figcaption>Comidas típicas</figcaption>
            </a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
            <a href="parques.asp" title="Parques | Guarapari">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="200" height="150" title="Parques | Guarapari">
            <figcaption>Parques</figcaption>
            </a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
            <a href="praias.asp" title="Praias de Guarapari">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="200" height="150" title="Praias de Guarapari">
            <figcaption>Praias</figcaption>
            </a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="destaquestutisticos_comidastipicas">
            <a href="turismo-rural-guarapari.asp" title="Turismo rural | Guarapari">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150" width="200" height="150" title="Turismo rural | Guarapari">
            <figcaption>Turismo rural</figcaption>
            </a>
    </figure>

</section>
```

> A pseudo-classe :first-of-type representa o primeiro elemento de seu tipo entre os filhos de seu elemento pai

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa seria utilizar o `flex`. Tão simples quanto:

```css
section{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/150x150'>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/150x150'>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/150x150'>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/150x150'>
</section>
```

Assim, caso queira mudar o display de linhas para colunas, só precisa mudar uma o `flex-direction: row;` para `flex-direction: column`.

**O que está sendo feito?**

Quando utiliza-se `display: flex;` pode-se criar displays fluidos, e, nesse caso específico, definir o flow para linhas (row). Assim, o css informa que deve-se apresentar os elementos internos em linha.
A linha `justify-content: space-between;` diz, literalmente *"Justifique o conteúdo pelo espaço entre ele"*. Desta forma, o primeiro item será alinhado ao começo do elemento pai e o último ao seu fim. Todos os demais serão alinhados para manter espaçamento igual entre eles.

Seria ideal manter as imagens com tamanho relativo (utilizando as unidades `%`, `vh` ou `vw`) para garantir a responsividade do design.

Não vejo motivo para complicar mais o processo.

Contudo, este código não funcionará em navegadores antigos.

Abaixo, alternativa com tamanho dinâmico de imagens:

```css
section{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

section img{
  width: 23%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/500x300'>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/500x300'>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/500x300'>
  <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/500x300'>
</section>
```

Usei `width: 23%;` nas imagens para manter margens entre elas (4 elementos com 23% de largura = 92%);

Para seu exemplo, seria ideal colocar um `div` que separe o título das cards de imagens.