# Como corrigir a sobreposição de slides durante a transição?

Tags: css

Tenho uma `aside` com elementos de transição de imagens (slides) que ajustam o seu tamanho de acordo com a dimensão do navegador.

Quando o navegador está em uma dimensão que não redimensiona os banners, tudo funciona perfeitamente bem. Como no exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema aparece quando a dimensão do navegador faz com que os banners ajustem suas medidas. Como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que ocorre quando os banners são redimensionados devido a largura do navegador é que no momento exato da transição há uma sobreposição de imagem. Quando a imagem muda, a sobreposição some, ficando o banner normal até a transição ocorrer novamente. Veja na foto abaixo o efeito da sobreposição:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurei diversos meios, mas nada de corrigir a situação.

**CSS e HTML**

```css
aside{
background-color: #ccc;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

.rslideslt {
width: 100%;
max-width: 300px;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.rslideslt li {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
display: none;
}

.rslideslt li:first-child {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
}

.rslideslt img {

height: auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<aside>
      <ul class="rslideslt">     

          <li>          
          <img src="./propaganda_lateral/001.jpg">
          </li>

          <li>          
          <img src="./propaganda_lateral/002.jpg">
          </li>

          <li>          
          <img src="./propaganda_lateral/003.jpg">
          </li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="rslideslt">

          <li>          
          <img src="./propaganda_lateral/004.jpg">
          </li>

      </ul>


      <ul class="rslideslt">

          <li>          
          <img src="./propaganda_lateral/005.jpg">
          </li>

      </ul>

 </aside>
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218191/como-distribuir-imagens-horizontalmente-por-igual-dentro-de-um-elemento-section/218202#218202

Comment: Não resolveu infelizmente.

Comment: Será que tem alguma coisa a ver a maquina, programas abertos e coisa e tal? Navegador? Pode passar o links da pagina?