# Como fazer para a quantidade de DIV se adaptar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde, minha duvida é a seguinte, no meu site tem uma seção onde fica a parte de destaques, e nessa seção tem mais 6 DIVs para a exibição dos produtos (imagem)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem, até aí tudo bem, o problema é que quando você da zoom, eles começam a se agrupar em baixo e fica bagunçado com a parte de baixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu imaginei como solução para esse problema é que enquanto ele vai dando zoom, ao invés de se organizar em baixo ele simplesmente sumir, porém não sei como fazer isso... E esse é o melhor jeito de arrumar isso?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218191/como-distribuir-imagens-horizontalmente-por-igual-dentro-de-um-elemento-section/218198#218198 amigo de uma olhada neste link na minha resposta. no tópico se desprendendo do número fixo de imagens, acredito que seja isso.

Comment: Tu não deve estar usando clearfix.
Da uma olhada nesse video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUPpnCnB7uo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se é isso que você quer...

```css
#conteiner{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}
.item{
  flex-basis: auto;
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteiner">
  <div class="item">Ítem 1</div>
  <div class="item">Ítem 2</div>
  <div class="item">Ítem 3</div>
  <div class="item">Ítem 4</div>
  <div class="item">Ítem 5</div>
  <div class="item">Ítem 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso, vlw!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que utilizar o sistema de grid do [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) resolveria o seu problema.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <!-- Conteúdo-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <!-- Conteúdo-->
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Adapte esse código a sua necessidade e assim deve resolver o seu problemas.

Comment: E se ele tiver um projeto com 300 páginas, e várias dessas páginas precisassem de uma adaptação das divs, você indicaria o bootstrap como resposta? O bootstrap é um excelente framework, mas que precisa ser usado desde o inicio de um projeto para suprir bem as necessidades.

Comment: Se ele tiver um projeto com 300 páginas com certeza ele vai querer usar o bootstrap ou qualquer outro framework que ajude na escalabilidade do site.

Comment: Não me foi muito útil neste problema, mas solucionou um outro problema que eu estava tendo, vlw